# ¿Cómo consumir una api con Autorization basic oauth con nodejs https?

Tags: javascript, nodejs, api, express, get

Hola estoy aprendiendo a consumir **apis** y estoy tratando de consumir una que utiliza **Authorization basic auth** donde le entrego por postman usuario, contraseña y gran-type retornando un **token**. Ahora estoy tratando de hacerlo con **node.js** pero no entiendo como pasarle los parámetros con un GET:

```
const https = require('https');

const postheader = {
        'Content-Type' : 'aplication/json',
        'cache-control' : 'no-cache'
    };

const optionspost={
        host : 'https://api.ejemplo.com',
        port : 443,
        path : '/oauth2-authentication/oauth/token
        username=eidverifier&password=admin&grant_type=password',
        method : 'GET',
        header : postheader
    };
};
const req = https.request(optionspost, (res) => {});
```

como le tengo que entregar el username , password y el grant_type, para que me regrese un json con el token?

Answer (score 0):

Lo solucione con esto

```
var https = require("https");
var url = "http://api.example.com/api/v1/?param1=1&param2=2";

var options = {
    host: "https://api.example.com",
    port: 443,
    method: "GET",
    path: url,//I don't know for some reason i have to use full url as a path
    auth: username + ':' + password
};

http.get(options, function(rs) {
    var result = "";
    rs.on('data', function(data) {
        result += data;
    });
    rs.on('end', function() {
        console.log(result);
    });
});
```